# Add selected listView and editText as a row to SQlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I start a new activity that is supposed to addRow  to the db(two fields:  ListView item title and an entry from editText). When retrieving rows on the the mainActivity, it shows only one column which means that only one field has been added. 
How can I store the clicked listView item to db?
Whats wrong with adding the editText value to db?

Here is addRow code:

```
Intent i = this.getIntent();
dataView.setText(i.getCharSequenceExtra("new item"));
mydManager = new DatabaseManager(this);

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = ListItemActivity.this.getIntent();        
            mydManager.addRow("Meat",dataView.getText().toString());//replace "meat" with selected listView item
            mydManager.close();
            ListItemActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Here is addRow method from DatabaseManager Class:

```
public boolean addRow(String g, String sub){
    ContentValues newEntry = new ContentValues();
    newEntry.put("Grocery", g); 
    newEntry.put("Sub_grocery", sub);         
    try{db.insertOrThrow(DB_TABLE, null, newEntry);}
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error in inserting rows ", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;           
    }
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

Here is the retrieve rows method from databaseManager class:

```
public ArrayList<String> retrieveRows(String listViewItem){//selected listView as argument "ex: Meat"
    ArrayList<String> productRows=new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"Grocery", "Sub_grocery"};
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{listViewItem};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        productRows.add(cursor.getString(0) + ", "+cursor.getString(1)+", ");
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }  
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return productRows;
}
```

And here how table is created:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (Grocery TEXT, Sub_grocery TEXT);";
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try retrieving it like this, and check your log cat.

```
           String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE;
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

           if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {   
                          Log.d("database",cursor.getString(0));
                          Log.d("database",cursor.getString(1));
                     }
              while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```